# How to program MTP IC (SST27SF020)?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, integrated-circuit, cmos

I found an IC ( **SST27SF020** ) from old CD player. On searching it's data sheet I found that it's a 256K x8 CMOS, MTP(Many-Time Programmable) and can be electrically erased and programmed at least 1000 times using an external programmer with a 12 volt power supply. Can anyone suggest, how to program these IC..?

> *I don't have PICkit or any other device other than Arduino UNO.* :-(

[image: SST27SF020]

[SST27SF020 data sheet](http://www.datasheet.hk/download.php?id=1596231&pdfid=ADD6FBAE7C283185C4FBBF02EAE4730B&file=0299%5C27sf020_1408572.pdf)

Comment: You could make it with your UNO. Use multistage CMOS counter for the address lines (say 4040 + couple of UNO lines for higher blocks) , 8 bit serial I/O for data and a couple of lines for control. Interface the 12V using a logic level driven high side switch - NPN/PNP.  Would make a nice little project for the dark winter months.

Answer (score 2):

Any "[universal programmer](http://www.dataman.com/programmers/universal.html)" with 32-40 pin socket should be able to support this classic EEPROM chip. But it will cost you a couple hundred $$, or $30 - $100 on eBay.